# Disqus visual glitch with WooThemes Wordpress Theme?

Tags: css

Quick help needed!  As you can see @ http://www.wokai.org/news/?p=1496, our Disqus box is overflowing and I'm not quite sure why.  I looked for the usual suspects and try some tricks but wasn't fruitful.  Can anyone offer a quick fix?

PS - This is for Wokai.org, a nonprofit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is. You have the .clearfix style strangely set to height: 0. Since that class is assigned to #dsq-content things are falling to pieces. What you should do is replace your custom .clearfix styles (style_default.css, line 48), with the styles suggested by http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your .clearfix class has height set to 0. All the stuff in it is still displaying, but the stuff below it is displaying in the same place. Remove that and it displays fine.

To go into more detail. Once the page is finished loading, some javascript has added `class="clearfix"` to the `<div id="dsq-content">`, but your `.clearfix` style in `style_default.css` has `height: 0;`, which when applied to dsq-content is causing it to display under the content after it.

Removing `height: 0` from `style_default.css` is causing the page to render properly.

Also in `disqus.js` on line 2543 is where it's adding the class to the dsq-content div. Removing this line may solve the issue as well. Or possibly setting it to use a different clearing class without height: 0.